# How to transform a DB2 hard-coded view into an Oracle view

Tags: oracle, view, db2

I have created this view in DB2 LUW:

```
CREATE VIEW SCHEMA.TYPE(TYPEID, TYPENAME) AS
SELECT TYPEID, TYPENAME
  FROM TABLE(VALUES(0,'A'),
                   (1,'B'),
                   (2,'C'),
                   (3,'D'),
                   (4,'E'),
                   (5,'F')) T(TYPEID, TYPENAME)
```

I'd like to move this same view to an Oracle database (10g).
I found that TABLE exists in Oracle, but the VALUES function does not.

Would you have an idea how to transform the view?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I came up with is:

```
CREATE VIEW SCHEMA.TYPE(TYPEID, TYPENAME)
AS
SELECT 0,'A' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 1,'B' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 2,'C' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 3,'D' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 4,'E' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 5,'F' FROM DUAL
```

Comment: "UNION ALL" instead of "UNION" as a minor improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Your other option is to just create the table and insert the values into it. Then, you'll get the added benefit of being able to put constraints on it, referential integrity, the works. Make it an index-organised table. Plus, it might give performance benefits to queries that use it.

Comment: Thanks! This view is a helper for an third-party database. We don't want to add references that might have an impact on the upgrade process of this database.